# custom python package not installing dependencies

Tags: python, pypi

I've been trying to create a custom python package and uploading to pypi using the standard

```
python -m build
```

```
python -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```

The building of the package and uploading works fine however whenever I try to pip install the said package with:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ rowan-ds-tools-2==0.1
```

I keep getting errors surrounding the install_requires packages listed in my setup.cfg. An example would be:

"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SQLAlchemy==1.4.22 (from rowan-ds-tools-2) (from versions: 1.3.4.dev0, 1.4.0b1, 2.0.0b1.dev0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for SQLAlchemy==1.4.22"

I can't tell why the package dependencies are not installing correctly, a link to my source code is here:

https://github.com/RowanMankoo/rowan_ds_tools

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[pip]+test.pypi.org

Comment: `pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple rowan-ds-tools-2==0.1`